# How to use SSIS , server side, without SSDT?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Is it required to use SSDT or Visual Studio to create packages for server side SSIS?

I thought there was another way, but the docs I find keep referring to the above tools.

(When I use the SQL Server "Import & Export Data" tool, it offers me the option to save the profile to a server, but I don't know where it goes?)

Answer (score 1):

Could you be thinking of BIML (Business Intelligence Markup Language)? This can be used to generate SSIS packages.

Apparently there's a commercial version, and an open-source version. The open source version appears to integrate into Visual Studio (per [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3094/introduction-to-business-intelligence-markup-language-biml-for-ssis/) at MSSQL Tips from 2013), so I can't say whether this is really a solution that uses other tools.

Note, of course, that an SSIS package is stored as an XML file with the extension `.dtsx`, so (in theory, at least) it might be possible to create one with a text editor. However, having dug through these to some extent, there's a lot of IDs and interlinkages amongst things, and it's not an experiment I personally would want to try.

The packages created by the import/export tool should be able to be saved either as a file, or to a server. Depending on the configuration of the server, and the options selected, they may wind up either stored in that server's `msdb` databases, or in a particular folder on the server (usually under the SQL root directory for the instance, in the subfolder `\DTS\Packages\`).